# ESP-IDF to work with external lib: Called idf_component_register from a non-component directory

Tags: cmake, esp-idf

I'm trying to add this compatibility layer to my project which makes use of the tinyGPSplus library

compat layer: https://github.com/andyfinity/TinyGPSPlus-ESPIDF

actual project: https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus

Followed these steps:

- cloned recursive the project to my components/ folder
- modified my CMakeLists.txt to include the reference:

```
+add_subdirectory($ENV{IDF_PATH}/components/tinygpsplus $ENV{IDF_PATH}/sample-uart-gps/tinygpsplus_build)
```

After building I keep receiving the message Called idf_component_register from a non-component directory.

modified the directories to keep a flat structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── library.json
├── library.properties
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── TinyGPS++.cpp
└── TinyGPS++.h

1 directory, 7 files
```

also modified the CMakeLists.txt:

```
idf_component_register(
  SRCS "TinyGPS++.cpp"
  INCLUDE_DIRS "."
)
```

But I keep receiving the error :(